# JavaScript and Server Commands

Tags: javascript, webserver

This might sound stupid, but can JavaScript be used for hacking - can it be used to do server-side commands like set server variables or access files stored in the server but not released to the internet?

Comment: This Site is For Helping in Development Not for hacking

Comment: The purpose of this question is to verify the security of my site, not to try and hack others' sites.

Answer (score 0):

No, JavaScript is a client side language.

Although JavaScript can be used to perform some action at the client side (like send your password via ajax call), but it is not even executed on the server.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely true - nowdays there are Javascript server-side solutions as well - look at node.js. Keeping that in mind, there are probably some ways (taking advantage of security holes etc) to run malicious javascript on server side.